# Manual configuration of create-react-app proxy

Tags: reactjs, proxy, create-react-app

I'm trying to move my proxy config out of my `package.json` and move it into a `setupProxy.js`, [as per the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually), however I'm failing at the first hurdle.

My react app (created with CRA) is running on http://localhost:3000/. My API is running on https://localhost:7146.

With the `package.json` approach, everything works as expected - calls to the server succeed.

```json
"proxy": "https://localhost:7146",
```

First request executed is

> GET
> http://localhost:3000/
> Status 200 OK

However when I remove this line from package.json, create a `setupProxy.js` file and try and configure it, I cant get it working.

```js
// setupProxy.js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

const setupProxy = (app) => {
  app.use("/",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://localhost:7146",
      changeOrigin: true,
    }),
  );
};

module.exports = setupProxy;
```

The first request executed is

> GET
> http://localhost:3000/
> Status 500 Internal Server Error
> Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/

Can anyone help me understand how to configure the proxy via setupProxy.js? I'm finding the docs pretty limited in this area. I've tried different middleware paths (`/`, `*`, `/api`) but I get the same error. I've tried not specifying a middleware path in `app.use` and instead specifying it only as a `createProxyMiddleware` parameter and still get the same error.

---

Note, I understand that this example is super basic and there is no need to use setupProxy over the package.json approach, however I plan to do some more complicated configuration as soon as I get the basics nailed down.

Comment: `GET` request on `http://localhost:3000/` will return the html page you are currently on -  so you didn't test anything.

Comment: You can only proxy subroutes. Like `/api`. e.g. `app.use("/api",`

Comment: When I specify my subroute as the `api.use` parameter, the initial GET request (to load the page) works however the first request to the API fails with a 404 (`POST http://localhost:3000/graphql/`). The correct URL, when calling this endpoint directly, is `POST https://localhost:7146/graphql/`. The differences are the protocol and the port. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You have to contain all of your routes in `/api` (or any other name) if you want to use this proxy

Comment: This fails with the error *"Secure Connection Failed - Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"*

Comment: @devklick, from a debugging standpoint, does it work without using encryption i.e., `http`?